Implied proof of axiom of choice
As I understand it the axiom of choice is: For any set (A) a collection of non empty disjoint sets there exists (at least one set) that contains (exactly) one element of each of those sets. If we let B be the union of the sets in A, then shouldn't the power set of B contain such a set? If not, what am I missing?

Which axiom allows you to pick subsets?  There's something it requires you don't have here.

Perhaps it should, but it won’t if there is no such subset. Much as (in another formulation of the axiom of choice), perhaps the Cartesian product of nonempty sets should contain some elements (i.e. choice functions), but it won’t if no choice function exists.

You're right that if there is such a set, then it is a member of the power set of $B$. But the existence of such a set can't be established from the ZF axioms. You can apply specification to collect exactly the sets with the desired property, but nothing guarantees that the resulting collection is nonempty.
From Wikipedia:

In 1963, Paul Cohen employed the technique of forcing, developed for this purpose, to show that, assuming ZF is consistent, the axiom of choice itself is not a theorem of ZF. He did this by constructing a much more complex model that satisfies ZF¬C (ZF with the negation of AC added as axiom) and thus showing that ZF¬C is consistent.



If we let B be the union of the sets in A, then shouldn't the power set of B contain such a set?

You are presuming such a set exists. If choice sets for $A$ exist, they will certainly be in this power set, but if they don't, they won't be anywhere.
Compare to the choice function formulation of the axiom of choice. If $S_i$ are nonempty sets, then the axiom of choice says $\prod_i S_i$ is nonempty. If there are any choice functions, they will be in $\prod_i S_i,$ but if not, they won't be anywhere. The only difference here is that $\prod_i S_i$ is exactly the set of choice functions, so will be empty if there are no choice functions, whereas $P(B)$ contains more than just the choice sets, so won't be nonempty, even if it might not contain any choice sets for $A$.
